# Error:(85, 0) Could not get unknown property 'compileJava' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I want to make use of voice recognition CMUSphinx, when trying to sync using android studio gradle an error

```
Error:(85, 0) Could not get unknown property 'compileJava' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project
```

Here is where the problem occurs in the Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.asus.voicerecognition"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs/'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //Disable Automatic ndk-build call
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile files("${sdkDir}/platforms/android-${sdkVersion}/android.jar")
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

ant.importBuild 'assets.xml'
preBuild.dependsOn(list, checksum)
clean.dependsOn(clean_assets)

import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine '$ndkDir/ndk-build.cmd', '-D', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
    } else {
        commandLine '$ndkDir/ndk-build', '-D', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
/*def ndkDir = plugins.getPlugin('com.android.application').sdkHandler.getNdkFolder()
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "${ndkDir}/ndk-build.cmd"
}*/

ndkBuild.outputs.dir "libs"
ndkBuild.outputs.dir "obj"

task mkdir << {
    new File('build/generated-src/java').mkdirs()
}

task swigSb(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'swig',
            "-I../sphinxbase/include", "-I../sphinxbase/swig",
            "-java", "-package", "edu.cmu.pocketsphinx",
            "-outdir", "build/generated-src/java", "-o", "jni/sphinxbase_wrap.c",
            "../sphinxbase/swig/sphinxbase.i"
}

task swigPs(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'swig',
            "-I../sphinxbase/swig",
            "-I../pocketsphinx/include",
            "-I../pocketsphinx/swig",
            "-java", "-package", "edu.cmu.pocketsphinx",
            "-outdir",  "build/generated-src/java",
            "-o", "jni/pocketsphinx_wrap.c",
            "../pocketsphinx/swig/pocketsphinx.i"
}

compileJava.dependsOn mkdir
compileJava.dependsOn swigSb
compileJava.dependsOn swigPs
compileJava.dependsOn ndkBuild
ndkBuild.dependsOn swigSb
ndkBuild.dependsOn swigPs

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'build/generated-src/java'
        }
    }
}

jar.version = '5prealpha-nolib'

clean.dependsOn cleanNdkBuild
```

Comment: If you want to generate sources in your project, you have to add dependency on source generation. Overall, I recommend you to use pregenerated sources in your project instead.

Comment: thanks, it works sir